# Cannot use an edge sequence from another graph error

Tags: r, igraph

I am new to R and currently working on implementing an algorithm to prune all leaves from a multigraph, then go through each cycle in the resulting graph to further simplify them based on certain rules. I  am currently testing the algorithm for several data sets, and so far it has been working just fine except for one particular data set that gives me the error "Cannot use an edge sequence from another graph," which I find it to be weird because it works for a larger data set. I have spent the last couple of hours trying to detect the error to no avail. Below is my code:

```
pruneLeaf<-function(g){
   members<-membership(clusters(g,mode="strong"))
   strongly_connected=lapply(unique(members),function (x) 
                      induced.subgraph(g,which(members==x)))
   return (strongly_connected)
}

getNetflow<-function(g,node){
   #precondition: g is a graph and node is a vertex in graph g
   #postcondition: return the netflow from vertex node in graph g.
   inflow_list=incident_edges(g,node,mode="in")
   outflow_list=incident_edges(g,node,mode="out")
   inflow<-0
   outflow<-0
   for(item in edge_attr(g,"Quantity",inflow_list[[1]])){
       inflow<-inflow+item
       }
   for(item in edge_attr(g,"Quantity",outflow_list[[1]])){
       outflow<-outflow+item
      }
   return (inflow-outflow)
   }

modifyCycle<-function(g,node,netflow){
     #pre-condition:node of graph g has negative netflow
     #post-condition: eliminate transactions with the least priorities to           
     outflow_list=incident_edges(g,node,mode="out")
     if(length(outflow_list[[1]])==1){
        delete.edges(g,outflow_list[[1]])
       }
     else{
          priority_list=outflow_list[[1]][order(outflow_list[[1]]$Priority)]
          while(netflow<0){
          count=1
          edge=priority_list[count] #we begin with the lowest priority edge
          flow=edge$Quantity
          if(flow<= -netflow){ 
            netflow<-netflow+flow 
            g<-delete.edges(g,edge)
          }
          else{ #otherwise, we allow partial transfer to balance the netflow
              g<-set.edge.attribute(g,"Quantity",edge,flow+netflow)
              netflow<-0
              }
          count<-count+1
          }
          return (g)
          }
         }

 modifyGraph<-function(g){
      #precondition: g is an igraph object containing only cycles
      #postcondition: return an igraph with balanced flow at every cycle
      isDone=FALSE
      while(!isDone){
            vertices=V(g)
            isDone=TRUE
      for(node in vertices){
          netflow=getNetflow(g,node)
          if(netflow<0){
             g<-modifyCycle(g,node,netflow)
             isDone=FALSE
          }
         }
        }
       return (g)
      }

settlementGridlock<-function(g){
  #precondition: g is an igraph object
  #post-condition: return a list of graphs comprises of cyc 
  cyclic_graphs<-pruneLeaf(g)
  result<-lapply(cyclic_graphs,function(x) modifyGraph(x))
  return(result)
  }
```

Sorry for the rather long post but basically there are several functions above:

1. pruneLeaf: to clear all the leaves in a graph and return a list of strongly connected components of a graph
2. getNetflow: to calculate the net flow of a given node in a graph
3. modifyCycle: to remove edges based on a priority given so as to balance the
                 inflow and outflow of a given node
4. modifyGraph: this function iterates through the graph to balance inflow and 
              outflow at every single node
5. settlementGridlock: this function applies modifyGraph to every single  strongly connected component in a list produced by pruneLeaf(graph)

The error seems to result from the function modifyCycle as given by the error log:

```
Error in as.igraph.es(graph, index) : 
Cannot use an edge sequence from another graph. 
9 stop("Cannot use an edge sequence from another graph.") 
8 as.igraph.es(graph, index) 
7 i_set_edge_attr(graph = graph, name = name, index = index, value = value) 
6 set.edge.attribute(g, "Quantity", edge, flow + netflow) 
5 modifyCycle(g, node, netflow) 
4 modifyGraph(x) 
3 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2 lapply(cyclic_graphs, function(x) modifyGraph(x)) 
1 settlementGridlock(graph3)
```

Comment: Chances of getting answers would probably be higher if you a.) provided the single one data set among all the working ones, which yields the error, and if you b.) could reduce the code to the bare minimum that's necessary to reproduce the error. Like `library(igraph);g <- make_ring(3);g2 <- make_tree(10);set.edge.attribute(g, "label", E(g), "1");set.edge.attribute(g, "label", E(g2), "1")`.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of providing the data set, but the data is kind of confidential so I'm not sure if I can do that. What  I can provide is that the error happens on the modifyCycle function (the rest of the functions are there just in case I'm wrong).

Comment: The error happens in the line `g<-set.edge.attribute(g,"Quantity",edge,flow+netflow)`. But I guess it's hard to debug that "mess" without the data. (I'd be out anyway, I'm an R beginner in many ways, too, and not a programmer.)

Comment: Can you generate some dummy data to post?